# Conservation law and entropy condition

Tags: measure-theory, partial-differential-equations, entropy, hyperbolic-equations

Consider the initital value problem given by
\begin{eqnarray}
u_t+f(u)_x=0\\
u(x,0)=u_0(x)
\end{eqnarray}
where $f$ is Lipschitz continuous and $u_0 \in L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}).$

$u\in L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^+)$ is called  weak solution to the above IVP if it satisfies the following,
\begin{eqnarray} \int_{\mathbb{R}^\times\mathbb{R}^+} \left(u\phi_t + f(u)\phi_x\right)  dxdt + \int_{\mathbb{R}} u_0(x)\phi(0,x) dx = 0, 
\quad \forall \phi \in C_c^1(\mathbb{R} \times [0,\infty)).
\end{eqnarray}
$u\in L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^+)$ is called entropic weak solution to the above IVP if it satisfies the following,
\begin{eqnarray} \int_{\mathbb{R}^\times\mathbb{R}^+} \left(|u-k|\phi_t + \hbox{sgn}(u-k)(f(u)-f(k))\phi_x \right) dxdt + \int_{\mathbb{R}} u_0(x)\phi(0,x) dx \geq 0, 
\quad \forall k\in \mathbb{R} \text{ and } \phi \in C_c^1(\mathbb{R} \times [0,\infty)).
\end{eqnarray}
It is pretty natural to expect the following,

1. If $u$ is a smooth solution to the IVP, then $u$ is also entropic weak solution
2. For $f(u)=au,$ $a \in \mathbb{R},$ if $u$ is a weak solution then it is entropic weak solution, cf. [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3655693/418542).

I am unable to prove both of them.

P.S: I could prove if $u$ is smooth solution then it is weak solution. I feel some modification of this proof should give (1), which I could not.

Any comments or references would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @EditPiAf Yes but there is no satisfactory answer...

Comment: Maybe now there is... Are you able to adapt the proof to the case of smooth solutions? Note that for smooth solutions, entropy functions $\eta$ with flux $\psi$ satisfy the (in)-*equality* $\eta_t + \psi_x \leq 0$ in the strong sense (thus, also in the weak sense)

Comment: Yes.... As you rightly mentioned enough to prove the condition for smooth convex entropy (which simply follows from chain rule) and then approximating $\eta(u)=|u-k|$ by smooth convex function completes the proof. Thank you so much for the comment.